# $A$ ring, $\mathfrak{m}$ maximal ideal - then $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{m}A_\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2A_\mathfrak{m}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, localization

According to lemma 4.2.3 of Qing Liu's book on Algebraic Geometry, the canonical homomorphism $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 \to \mathfrak{m}A_\mathfrak{m}/ \mathfrak{m}^2 A_\mathfrak{m}$ is an isomorphism of $A/\mathfrak{m}$ vector spaces.

To show this, the book proves that $\varphi: A/\mathfrak{m} \to A_\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}A_\mathfrak{m}$ is an isomorphism and says it suffices to tensor this map by $\otimes_A \mathfrak{m}$. I don't know why this is enough, wouldn't it be required that $\mathfrak{m}$ is a flat $A$-module?

Comment: To add to the answer below: if $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic, then so are $M\otimes L$ and $N\otimes L$, with no further hypotheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\m}{\mathfrak m}$
You have an exact sequence, regardless of flatness:
$\m\otimes_A \m \to \m\to \m\otimes_A A/\m\to 0$ (note that flatness would add a leftmost $0$ but we don't need it)

Moreover, the image of $\m\otimes_A\m\to \m$ is clearly $\m^2$. *This is not to say* that $\m\otimes_A\m \cong \m^2$ which would indeed require flatness of $\m$. It follows that $\m/\m^2\cong \m\otimes_A A/\m$

Similarly, one has an exact sequence $\m\otimes_A \m A_\m \to \m A_\m\to \m\otimes_A A_\m/\m A_\m\to 0$, and we now have to check that the image of $\m\otimes_A \m A_\m \to \m A_\m$ is $\m^2 A_\m$, but this is clear too; and so similarly $\m A_\m/\m^2A_\m\cong \m\otimes_A A_\m/\m A_\m$